# AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'register_extensions'

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I was running lesson1 of fast.ai in google-colab. When I came to the line

```
img = plt.imread(f'{PATH}valid/cats/{files[0]}')

plt.imshow(img);
```

It didn't show an image. Instead I got an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'register_extensions'
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 14):

I was on Google Colab when I encountered this issue.

**After** the code to install `torch`, add:

```
!pip install pillow==4.1.1
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload
```

The [`%autoreload`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html#autoreload) will reload all modules so no kernel restart is required.

Credit goes to [this forum post](https://forums.fast.ai/t/attributeerror-module-pil-image-has-no-attribute-register-extensions/10689/27).

Answer (score 9):

For me restarting the runtime using “Runtime / Restart runtime…” from the menu after installing the newer Pillow using pip and running the code that uses it fixed the issue.

Comment: I did the same. I confirmed the correct version was loaded (using !cat) and for some reason the runtime needs to be restarted...

Comment: Whats the version of pillow? I still got this using 5.1.0

Comment: It works for me with version 5.3 on Google Colab. [Here's how I installed it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53496816/5353461).

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me after loading the module `pillow` and all the other fastai setup is this:

```
# workaround 
from PIL import Image
def register_extension(id, extension): Image.EXTENSION[extension.lower()] = id.upper()
Image.register_extension = register_extension
def register_extensions(id, extensions): 
  for extension in extensions: register_extension(id, extension)
Image.register_extensions = register_extensions
```

and no Runtime Restart is now required.

Comment: This workaround seemed to rid of the error, but not sure if there's other problems downstream. Will update later.

Comment: In my case, the snippet above removes register_extensions error but, also lead to another error `AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'register_decoder'`

Comment: This seems to be a totally different issue, @DavidJung. Perhaps this will help: https://github.com/pytorch/examples/issues/429?

Comment: -1: I also get `AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'register_decoder'`. I got it working with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53496816/5353461).

Answer (score 5):

run these 3 lines at the start of your colab notebook

```
!pip install Pillow==4.0.0
!pip install PIL
!pip install image
```

I was also struggling with the same issue. But this has worked for me.
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html

Answer (score 5):

Your installed Pillow version is not up-to-date. Run the following:

```
import PIL
print(PIL.PILLOW_VERSION)
```

It will probably be `4.0.0`. If so, run the following commands:

```
!pip uninstall Pillow
!pip install Pillow==5.3.0
```

Then restart your runtime (press `CTRL + M .`, or `Runtime --> Restart runtime` from the menu). Run the first set of commands again to ensure your current PIL version is 5.3.0.

Answer (score 2):

Next time, you start your colab VM, be sure to comment out the following two lines (i.e do not run them)

```
#%reload_ext autoreload        <------------— comment out 
#%autoreload 0                 <------------— comment out
%matplotlib inline
```

Just to be safe, I also reinstalled my PIL

```
!pip install --no-cache-dir -I pillow
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after I added the following after all the setup:

```
from PIL import Image

def register_extension(id, extension): Image.EXTENSION[extension.lower()] = id.upper()
Image.register_extension = register_extension
def register_extensions(id, extensions): 
  for extension in extensions: register_extension(id, extension)
Image.register_extensions = register_extensions
```

and then changed the the following function in section `Analyzing Results: Looking At Pictures`

```
def load_img_id(ds, idx): return np.array(PIL.Image.open(PATH+ds.fnames[idx]))
```

to

```
def load_img_id(ds, idx): return np.array(Image.open(PATH+ds.fnames[idx]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the format of the file. I changed it from ".tiff" to ".png". It works. The module does not have tiff decoder.

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
python -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

and restarting python/re-importing the module fixed this for me.